# regex c# string

Tags: c#

I would like to transform this claim that I get `"[\" 75 \ ", \" 91 \ "]"` to `(75,91)`

I used regex.split but I don't know how to do it.

```
if (Zone != null)
{
    filtrer.Append(" and depalcement in (");

    foreach (string i in Zone)
    {
        var diviser=Regex.Split(i, @"\");
        filtrer.Append(diviser);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your input actually JSON? Then you´re better off using JsonConvert than trying to parse this yourself.

Comment: If your input is not JSON, show the actual input.

Comment: You are not trying to build up an SQL statement here, are you?

Comment: oui je veux de créer une Requete sql

Comment: Stack Overflow is english-only. Please try and stick to it, thanks. @KOMARA ( SO est en anglais uniquement. Si vous le pouvez, veuillez vous en tenir à l'anglais. )

Answer (score 2):

No Regex, just JSON. Try this:

```
var content = "[\"75\",\"91\"]";
var list = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(content);
    
var numbers = list.Select(int.Parse);
    
foreach(var number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness; to get from `"[\" 75 \", \" 91 \"]"` to `(75,91)` using regex the code could be something like this:

```
var s2 = "(" + Regex.Replace(input: s, pattern: "[^0-9,]", "") + ")"; // or @"[^\d,]"
```

Pattern:

- `[...]` - character set aka character class aka 'any of'
- `^` - negate
- `0-9` or `\d` - digit
- `,` comma
- together it's *any character that isn't a digit or a comma*